# Definition of field extensions: Can we talk about extensions like $\mathbb{F}_3(5)/\mathbb{F}_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

First of all, sorry for this absolute beginner question. It has been bothering me a lot and I think I am just getting something conceptually wrong here.

I am learning about extension fields and use the following definition:

> An extension field $F(\alpha)/F$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $\alpha$.

What I am confused about is, what values can be used for $\alpha$ - especially, when working with finite fields of the form $\mathbb{F}_p$.

I have been trying to show that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{\alpha}$ over $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ is $x^2 - \alpha$. First it seemed obvious, since the roots of $x^2 - \alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ are $\sqrt{\alpha}$ and $2\sqrt{\alpha}$, both of which are not in $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$. On a second thought I got uncertain about my argument, though. What if $\alpha = 1$?

According to above definition $\mathbb{F}_3(1) = \mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{1})/\mathbb{F}_3(1) = \mathbb{F}_3$. Even though we are not really extending the field $\mathbb{F}_3(1)$, we should still be able to talk about the extension field $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{1})/\mathbb{F}_3(1)$. But then both $\sqrt{1} = 1$ and $2\sqrt{1} = 2$ are in $\mathbb{F}_3(1)$ and $x^2 - 1 = (x + 1) (x + 2)$, in which case $x^2 - \alpha$ would not be irreducible.

This confusion made me think generally about what would happen for different values of $\alpha$. If $\alpha = 2$, we would actually extend the field $\mathbb{F}_3(2) = \mathbb{F}_3$, because $2$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_3(2)$ and if $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$, then $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{F}_3$ actually extends $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{\sqrt{2}})/\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{2})$ is also an actual extension of $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{2})$ (i.e. not equal to $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{2})$ itself).

But what about a value like $\alpha = 5$? Would $5$ be treated as $2$ (as if it was an element of $\mathbb{F}_3$)? Or would the elements of $\mathbb{F}_3(5)$ be of the form $a + 5b$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{F}_3$? This would seem a bit strange. On the other hand, why would we interpret $5$ as an element of $\mathbb{F}_3$, when we want to extends the field with something that is explicitly not in the field (like in the case of $\sqrt{2})$.

To summarise, I have the following specific questions:

- Is my reasoning that $x^2 - \alpha$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ correct? And if so, what about the case $\alpha = 1$?
- Would the extension $\mathbb{F}_3(5) / \mathbb{F}_3$ be the same as $\mathbb{F}_3(2)/\mathbb{F}_3 = \mathbb{F}_3$ or would the elements of $\mathbb{F}_3(5)$ be of the form $a + 5b$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{F}_3$? In the first case, why would we interpret $5$ as being an element of $\mathbb{F}_3$ as opposed to $\sqrt{2}$?

I know, these are very basic questions, but I really want to get these foundations right and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Correct. We have $2=5$ as elements of $\Bbb{F}_3$. Also $2=-1$, meaning that $\Bbb{F}_3(\sqrt2)$ and $\Bbb{F}_3(\sqrt{-1})$ can also be equated.

Comment: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ so it is not irreducible over any field.

Comment: But it may easily happen that $x^2-\alpha$ is reducible over $\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$. For example, if $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^2+1$ in an extension field of $\Bbb{F}_3$, then
$$(1-\alpha)^2=1-2\alpha+\alpha^2=(1+\alpha^2)+\alpha=\alpha.$$ This means that $x^2-\alpha$ has its roots $\pm(1-\alpha)$ already in $\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ and we need not extend the field further.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Ok, I suspected that $2 = 5$, but why would we treat $5$ as an element of $\mathbb{F}_5$, as opposed to $\sqrt{2}$? Regarding your second comment: Does this mean that $x^2 - \alpha$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$?

Comment: So can the question, whether $x^2 - \alpha$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ not be answered in general? Would that also mean that if I want to determine whether $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{\alpha})/\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ is a separable extension, I would have to consider the two cases when $x^2 - \alpha$ is irreducible and when it's not?

Comment: For a simple field extension $K(\alpha)$ to make sense we really already need a bigger field $\Omega$ containing $K$ in the background. For otherwise we have no idea how e.g. the arithmetic operations involving $\alpha$ and the elements of $K$ should work. So because we already know of $\Bbb{R}$ we can think of fields like $\Bbb{Q}(\root5\of2)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\pi)$ without any problems.

Comment: (cont'd) But, particularly when first constructing finite fields, we don't have anything that would serve in the role of $\Omega$. So we need to use the method of 1) finding an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$, 2) construct the quotien ring (known to be a field) $K=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, 3) define the element $\alpha=x+\langle f(x)\rangle\in K$ which happens to be a root of $f(x)$, and 4) observe that (with $\Omega=K$) we have $K=\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$.

Comment: Unlike with $5$ we don't have a natural way of treating $\sqrt2$ as an element of $\Bbb{F}_5$ We can construct a quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]/\langle 3\rangle$ , and this turns out be a field of 9 elements, isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_3[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$.

Comment: No, we cannot give general definite answer to whether $x^2-\alpha$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$. It depends on the meaning of $\alpha$. Your question about separability, on the other hand, can be answered easily. Either case-by-case as you described, or by observing that if $\beta$ is root of $x^2-\alpha$ then $-\beta$ is the other.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. This helped a lot!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If time permits you may write an answer based on your comments. Many users don't bother to read all comments.

Comment: Done @ParamanandSingh. Sorry about taking my time. I have mixed feelings about answers like this (undoubtedly you have noticed). Also I have been more than bit stressed this Spring. It may be prudent to clean up the comments now, but I cannot point at a natural cutting point :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to clear some of the fog.

---

Let's start from the question in the title. When discussing field extensions of the form $k(\alpha)$, where $k$ is a known field, and $\alpha$ is an entity usually not in $k$, we need to exercise some care. The notation $k(\alpha)$ means the smallest field containing both $k$ and $\alpha$, but that simple description is oversimplified without some suitable context. Namely, we are tacitly assuming that there exists at least one field, call it $\Omega$ containing both $k$ and $\alpha$. And then we take the smallest subfield *within the umbrella field $\Omega$* that contains both $k$ and $\alpha$. This is actually necessary. After all, for $k(\alpha)$ to be a field we need to know how the arithmetic operations involving $\alpha$ and elements of $k$ work. The definition of the field $\Omega$ contains such details, and we can proceed safely with the usual definition (= take the intersection of all the subfield of $\Omega$ that contain both $k$ and $\alpha$, and then prove that the said intersection is itself a subfield, and obviously minimal among such subfields).

On a first course in extension fields this point does not get much attention. That is largely because we are tacitly working inside $\Omega=\Bbb{C}$, where we can merrily adjoin complex numbers to $\Bbb{Q}$ and friends. But when extending fields like $\Bbb{F}_3$ we don't have a convenient $\Omega$ at our disposal, and need to exercise some care. To make sense of $\Bbb{F}_3(5)$ we first need to interpres $5$ in the language that can extend that of $\Bbb{F}_3$. It is a stretch to assign to $5$ a meaning other than
$$5=1+1+1+1+1.$$
But this gives us the decisive clue. In the field $\Bbb{F}_3$ we have $1+1+1=0$. So, by associativity of addition we must have
$$5=(1+1+1)+(1+1)=0+2=2.$$
Hence we can conclude that $5$ already is an element of $\Bbb{F}_3$, and we don't need to extend it at all!

The fields of the form $\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a zero of some irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{F}_3[x]$, require yet another way of thinking . The usual process is to define the extension field $K=\Bbb{F}_3[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ as a quotient ring of the polynomial ring by the maximal ideal generated by $f(x)$. Then we can declare $\alpha$ to be the coset $x+\langle f(x)\rangle$ that is then a zero of $f(x)$ in $K$. So $K$ can, at least temporarily, assume the role of $\Omega$. At that point the usual argument shows that actually $K=\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$.

---

Another theme in the question was whether $g(x)=x^2-\alpha$ is always irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$. Here the answer is *it depends*. As $g(x)$ is quadratic, it is irreducible over a field $K$ (containing its coefficients) if and only if it does not have a root in $K$. If we select $\alpha$ to be a zero of $x^2+1=x^2-2$, it turns out that then $x^2-\alpha$ has a zero in $\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$. Because $\alpha^2+1=0$ I will denote $\alpha=i="\sqrt{-1}"$ to make the calculations easier to follow. We see that $1-i\in\Bbb{F}_3(i)$ and
$$
(1-i)^2=1^2-2i+i^2=-2i=i,
$$
because $-2=1$ and hence also $-2i=i$. So $g(x)=x^2-i$ factors like
$$g(x)=(x-1+i)(x+1-i)\in\Bbb{F}_3(i)[x].$$
On the other hand, if we select $\alpha=1-i\in\Bbb{F}_3(i)=\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ it turns out that $x^2-\alpha$ is irreducible. One way of showing that is to observe that if $\beta$ satisfies $\beta^2=\alpha$, then $\beta^4=i$, and it quickly follows that $\beta$ has multiplicative order sixteen. The multiplicative group of $F_3(\alpha)$ has only $3^2-1=8$ elements, so it cannot contain an element of order sixteen. Therefore $x^2-(1-i)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_3(1-i)=\Bbb{F}_3(i)$, and $\beta$ generates a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{F}_3(i)$. That is, a field of $3^4=81$ elements.

Compare this with extensions of rationals. The polynomial $x^2-\sqrt2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. For its zero, call it $\gamma$, is a root of $x^4-2$ and that polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein. On the other hand many elements of $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ have square roots in $L$. Such as $\alpha=(1+\sqrt2)^2=3+2\sqrt2$. Hence $L(\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2})=L=\Bbb{Q}(3+2\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for writing out this answer! This is super helpful!